# Не могу подключить библиотеку jQuery і slick.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Видает такие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я подключаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю все з официального сайта, а Слайдер скачал и подключил из папки

Comment: slick-min переместите после app.js

Comment: не работает, тот же результат

Comment: Значит версия jquery не подходит

Comment: Что у вас в app.js на 9 строке ?

Comment: $('.slider').slick();  Добавляюю к слайдеру слик

Comment: В html точно селектор class="slider" ?

Comment: Да точно, все уже пробовал

Comment: @ЄвгенійАнатолійовичТкач Дал ответ ниже

Comment: @Євгеній Анатолійович Ткач Просьба в случае решения проблемы принять ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы пытаетесь подключить `slick.min.js` как css, используя `<link rel=`
а надо как скрипт используя `<script src=`

Comment: Да!!! Спасибо большое Вам!!! Все получилось!

Comment: @ЄвгенійАнатолійовичТкач тогда с Вас галочка возле ответа)